# return true is returning 0 in C++

Tags: c++

This is a simple recursive palindrome test that works in itself but returns 0 regardless of what the function actually returns. Here's my code, I left in debugging cout statements so you can see that it does indeed work:

```
bool pal(int l, int r, char *a)
{
     if(l >= r)
     {
        cout << "returning true" << endl;
        return true;
     }

     if(a[l] != a[r])
     {
        cout << "returning false" << endl;
        return false;
     }
     pal(l+1, r-1, a);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: What data are you calling it with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior because there is a path that does not return at all. You should add a `return` statement at the end:

```
return pal(l+1, r-1, a);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pal(l+1, r-1, a);
```

That calls `pal`, but discards the result.  It also leads to a situation in which no path returns a value (check your warnings!).  What you want is:

```
return pal(l+1, r-1, a);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks so much. It's funny, I was just looking over some old notes from class and I have this exact scenario labeled as "common mistakes."

Comment: @user1825211: It's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement in the end. Because if the function doesn't go inside if statement, there is no return value.

it can be something like

```
return pal(l+1, r-1, a);
```